# How do I make HttpPostedFile nullable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC Razor view whereby a user can attach a document based on some dropdown selection and I am getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on the file property each time I attempt a submission without attaching anything.

I want the file attachment (and thus HttpPostedFile) to be optional when the model is validated and saved.

This is how the controller looks like :

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AssetDisposal(AssetDisposalViewModel model,  HttpPostedFileBase PostedFile)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            genericService.LoadAssetDisposalTypes(model);
            genericService.LoadAssetDisposalMethods(model);
            genericService.LoadAssetDisposalBusinessUnits(model);
            genericService.LoadAssetDisposalUsers(model);
            genericService.LoadAssetDisposalOffices(model);
            return View(model);
        }                
        ..............
        ..............
        ..............
           
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var ast = new AssetDisposal();
            model.UpdateModel(ast);               
            genericService.AddAssetDisposal(server);
          
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(PostedFile.FileName))
            {
               //some logic here
               //return
            }
            //Extract filename only when UIcontrol has file
            else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(PostedFile.FileName))
            {
                string FileExt = Path.GetExtension(PostedFile.FileName).ToUpper();
                var fileName = String.Format("{1}{2}{0}", Path.GetFileName(PostedFile.FileName), user, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss_"));
                Session["fileName"] = Path.GetFileName(PostedFile.FileName);
                var path = "";                   
                path = @"C:\Users\username\Documents\AssetSysAttachments\" + fileName;
                Session["fileUrl"] = path;                 
                PostedFile.SaveAs(path);
            }
           
            return RedirectToAction("AssetDisposals");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("AssetDisposals");
    }
```

How should I handle optional attachment of the file ?

I have tried checking as below but still getting same error :

```
 if (PostedFile.ContentLength < 0)
            {
                //same logic here
            }
            else if (PostedFile.ContentLength > 0) 
            {
                //same logic here
            }
```

Trying `HttpPostedFile? PostedFile`  does not work either since non-nullable by definition.

Comment: `if(PostedFile != null)`?

Comment: that is not working as well !  same error